# How to suppress mysql stored procedure output?

Tags: mysql

so if i have a stored procedure that contains selects how to suppress the results from these selects from appearing ?

for example if i have

```
create procedure xyz
begin    
    select * from table_name #I don't want this to be seen in the console.    
    do other stuff     
end;
```

Comment: Then remove it or what do you need it for?

Comment: the select gets stuff that is stored into a variable. Therefore it is needed but i don't want the select result to show in the terminal

Comment: When I select into a variable in my procs it doesn't output to console.  I do it this way SELECT col INTO varname FROM  tablename etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set the required params into variables like

SET @foo = (SELECT foo_coloumn FROM foo_table);

This will suppress the select result set.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me since the resultset was multirow. I did figure out a solution, though:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE silence_output SELECT * FROM foo;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE silence_output;
```

This avoids any multirow/multicolumn issues that might be encountered by dumping the resultset into a table that is then trashed. Hope this helps someone else. You can name the temporary table anything.

Comment: If you work with things like `SELECT @res := coulmn_a, column_b, column_c, another_table.* FROM main_table`, this is the solution you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling to find a way to suppress multirow output in a stored procedure while at the same time locking all applicable rows with "FOR UPDATE".

First attempt was "SELECT ... INTO" with a "LIMIT" clause but that would only lock 1 row.

Using GROUP_CONCAT solved it for me:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column) INTO @variable 
FROM table 
WHERE column = value
FOR UPDATE
```

Doing that in a transaction locked all affected rows, prevented an insert, and suppressed output.